# How to add a Footer View (TextView) to the end of a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i am trying to make a layout like this:

```
actionbar   
==================== 
txtViewTitle
--------------------
listview item1
listview item2
listview item3
........scroll scroll scroll
...at the end of all the items:
-----------------
txtViewFooter
==================
linearlayout of buttons [always visible at the bottom]
-------------------------------
```

the part between the ==========s should be scrollable

here's my code, it works except for txtViewFooter which is displayed if the list is short enough to accomodate in part of the screen. but not displayed if list is longer and requores scroling

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/d_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:gravity="center|center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewTitle"
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<ListView  
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
android:id="@+id/my_list" 
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent">
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewFooter"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    />

<View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0.1dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_menu"
android:id="@+id/separator2"
android:visibility="visible"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#eeeeee">
    <include layout="@layout/footer_menu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can't use the footer in the way you want to. A footer is built into the list view, like an extra cell, and not a bracket at the end. You need to just add a separate view - like a text view - and then set its content programatically instead to using a footer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
ListView.addFooterView(View v)
```

to add a footer to your `ListView`. You **do not need to define the footer in .xml**

Example:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(Context);
tv.setText("I am a footer")

ListView.addFooterView(tv);
```

Inflate from .xml:

```
View footer = LayoutInflater.from(Context).inflate(R.layout.your_footer_layout, null);
ListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Make sure you add your footer or header `View` **before** you add other items to the list.

Comment: Just adding to your post, headers and footers are a fantastic thing to look into when it comes to UI development for Android, it can make a world of difference in developing apps, especially with multiple views.

Comment: that did it! thank you so much! ^_^ i didnt know about this listview footer thing!

Comment: wait. a part of the footerview hides beneath the sticky bottom menu. how to solve this?

Comment: probably an issue with another layout, have a look at your xml