# Android : How to add a listview inside a scrollview.?

Tags: android, listview, layout, scrollview

In an android application, I have a linear layout with vertical orientation. This layout contains 2 childs(listview and a textview). The problem is the layout has to show the textview only when the listview has finished scrolling. Plz help me to design the layout?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a Footer View (TextView) to the end of a ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388247/how-to-add-a-footer-view-textview-to-the-end-of-a-listview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

Comment: Actually @Setu's duplicate is better suited than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to know is when the listview is at the bottom or showing the last item, then make your textview visible, this code does the trick:

```
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(this);//The class must implement onscrolllistener

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView lw, final int firstVisibleItem,
                 final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {

    switch(lw.getId()) {
        case android.R.id.list:     

            // Make your calculation stuff here. You have all your
            // needed info from the parameters of this function.

            // Sample calculation to determine if the last 
            // item is fully visible.
             final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
           if(lastItem >= totalItemCount) {
              if(preLast!=lastItem){ //to avoid multiple calls for last item
                Log.d("Last", "Last");
                preLast = lastItem;
                //Make your text view visible
              }
           }
    }
}
```

Is also important to mention that "You Should not have a listview within a ScrollView.", it goes against the Android Design Guidelines and chances are that you are doing something terribly wrong if you go for that approach.

Hope it Helps!

Regards!

Comment: Thanks Martin. Your solution worked for me. I also took your suggestion and changed my implementation of having a listview inside a scrollview.